# Errors while Installing Garfield++

Tags: debugging, cmake

Apologies beforehand, I figure this is the kind of thing that probably has been posted about before but I couldn't find anything when I searched.

I'm trying to install Garfield++ and getting some error messages when I try to run the cmake. My system is running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and ROOT version 6.20/02.

Everything seems to go fine until I try `make -j N`

When that happens I get these errors.

```
[  0%] Generating GarfieldDict.cxx, libGarfieldDict_rdict.pcm, libGarfieldDict.rootmap
In file included from input_line_6:3:
In file included from /home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:18:
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TStorage.h:93:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'R__likely'
   ClassDef(TStorage,0)  //Storage manager class
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/Rtypes.h:327:4: note: expanded from macro 'ClassDef'
   _ClassDefOutline_(name,id,virtual,)   \
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/Rtypes.h:301:4: note: expanded from macro '_ClassDefOutline_'
   _ClassDefBase_(name,id, virtual_keyword, overrd)       \
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/Rtypes.h:276:11: note: expanded from macro '_ClassDefBase_'
      if (R__likely(recurseBlocker >= 2)) ...
          ^
In file included from input_line_6:3:
In file included from /home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:18:
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TStorage.h:93:13: error: 'TStorage' does not refer to a value
   ClassDef(TStorage,0)  //Storage manager class
            ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TStorage.h:33:7: note: declared here
class TStorage {
      ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TStorage.h:118:1: error: use of undeclared identifier 'R__INTENTIONALLY_UNINIT_BEGIN'
R__INTENTIONALLY_UNINIT_BEGIN
^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TStorage.h:120:1: error: use of undeclared identifier 'R__INTENTIONALLY_UNINIT_END'
R__INTENTIONALLY_UNINIT_END
^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TStorage.h:131:1: error: unknown type name 'R__NEVER_INLINE'
R__NEVER_INLINE void TStorage::UpdateIsOnHeap(volatile const UInt_t &uni...
^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TStorage.h:131:17: error: expected unqualified-id
R__NEVER_INLINE void TStorage::UpdateIsOnHeap(volatile const UInt_t &uni...
                ^
In file included from input_line_6:3:
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:133:4: error: unknown type name 'R__ALWAYS_INLINE'
   R__ALWAYS_INLINE Bool_t IsOnHeap() const { return TestBit(kIsOnHeap); }
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:133:27: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
   R__ALWAYS_INLINE Bool_t IsOnHeap() const { return TestBit(kIsOnHeap); }
                          ^
                          ;
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:169:30: error: unknown type name 'Bool_t'
   void     SetBit(UInt_t f, Bool_t set);
                             ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:172:4: error: unknown type name 'R__ALWAYS_INLINE'
   R__ALWAYS_INLINE Bool_t TestBit(UInt_t f) const { return (Bool_t) ((f...
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:172:21: error: duplicate member 'Bool_t'
   R__ALWAYS_INLINE Bool_t TestBit(UInt_t f) const { return (Bool_t) ((f...
                    ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:133:21: note: previous declaration is here
   R__ALWAYS_INLINE Bool_t IsOnHeap() const { return TestBit(kIsOnHeap); }
                    ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:172:27: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
   R__ALWAYS_INLINE Bool_t TestBit(UInt_t f) const { return (Bool_t) ((f...
                          ^
                          ;
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:210:11: error: unknown type name 'Bool_t'
   static Bool_t    GetObjectStat();
          ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:211:35: error: unknown type name 'Bool_t'
   static void      SetObjectStat(Bool_t stat);
                                  ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:215:4: error: unknown type name 'Bool_t'
   ClassDef(TObject,1)  //Basic ROOT object
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/Rtypes.h:327:4: note: expanded from macro 'ClassDef'
   _ClassDefOutline_(name,id,virtual,)   \
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/Rtypes.h:301:4: note: expanded from macro '_ClassDefOutline_'
   _ClassDefBase_(name,id, virtual_keyword, overrd)       \
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/Rtypes.h:273:20: note: expanded from macro '_ClassDefBase_'
   virtual_keyword Bool_t CheckTObjectHashConsistency() const overr...
                   ^
In file included from input_line_6:3:
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:215:4: error: use of undeclared identifier 'R__likely'
/home/jason/Root/build/include/Rtypes.h:327:4: note: expanded from macro 'ClassDef'
   _ClassDefOutline_(name,id,virtual,)   \
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/Rtypes.h:301:4: note: expanded from macro '_ClassDefOutline_'
   _ClassDefBase_(name,id, virtual_keyword, overrd)       \
   ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/Rtypes.h:276:11: note: expanded from macro '_ClassDefBase_'
      if (R__likely(recurseBlocker >= 2)) ...
          ^
In file included from input_line_6:3:
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:215:13: error: 'TObject' does not refer to a value
   ClassDef(TObject,1)  //Basic ROOT object
            ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:37:7: note: declared here
class TObject {
      ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:237:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'R__unlikely'
   if (R__unlikely(fgObjectStat)) TObject::AddToTObjectTable(this);
       ^
/home/jason/Root/build/include/TObject.h:261:8: error: use of undeclared identifier 'R__unlikely'
   if (R__unlikely(fgObjectStat)) TObject::AddToTObjectTable(this);
       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
Error: Error loading the default header files.
CMakeFiles/Garfield.dir/build.make:208: recipe for target 'GarfieldDict.cxx' failed
make[2]: *** [GarfieldDict.cxx] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Garfield.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Garfield.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

To be frank, I have only a vague idea what this means. I *think* it means that the Garfield++ cmake can find my ROOT but for some reason can't read it properly, which I don't know how to fix.

Any help would be appreciated.

I followed the instructions at https://garfieldpp.web.cern.ch/garfieldpp/getting-started/

- Phase 1 --
  The only deviation from the link was having to tell ccmake where my root directory was. 1st Phase - Checked Prerequisites: A C++ compiler that could support C++11, Root (at least version 6), GSL (GNU Scientific Library), and CMake (at least version 3.3). Only lacked GSL so I went to http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/gnu/ftp/gnu/gsl and, downloaded and installed version 2.6.
- Phase 2

  ```
  mkdir GARFIELD
  export GARFIELD_HOME=/home/GARFIELD
  git clone http://gitlab.cern.ch/garfield/garfieldpp.git $GARFIELD_HOME
  cd $GARFIELD_HOME
  mkdir build
  cd build
  cmake $GARFIELD_HOME
  make -j 4
  ```

The last step which has the failure. [Though I have noticed that the second to last step, while it runs, does leave a field blank. So here's the results of `cmake $GARFIELD_HOME`.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------------
-- Garfield source files: Source/AvalancheMC.cc;Source/AvalancheMicroscopic.cc;Source/Component.cc;Source/ComponentAnalyticField.cc;Source/ComponentAnsys121.cc;Source/ComponentAnsys123.cc;Source/ComponentCST.cc;Source/ComponentComsol.cc;Source/ComponentConstant.cc;Source/ComponentElmer.cc;Source/ComponentElmer2D.cc;Source/ComponentFieldMap.cc;Source/ComponentGrid.cc;Source/ComponentNeBem2d.cc;Source/ComponentNeBem3d.cc;Source/ComponentNeBem3dMap.cc;Source/ComponentTcad2d.cc;Source/ComponentTcad3d.cc;Source/ComponentUser.cc;Source/ComponentVoxel.cc;Source/DriftLineRKF.cc;Source/GeometryRoot.cc;Source/GeometrySimple.cc;Source/KDTree.cc;Source/Medium.cc;Source/MediumCdTe.cc;Source/MediumGaAs.cc;Source/MediumGas.cc;Source/MediumMagboltz.cc;Source/MediumSilicon.cc;Source/Numerics.cc;Source/OpticalData.cc;Source/PlottingEngineRoot.cc;Source/Polygon.cc;Source/Random.cc;Source/RandomEngineRoot.cc;Source/Sensor.cc;Source/Shaper.cc;Source/Solid.cc;Source/SolidBox.cc;Source/SolidExtrusion.cc;Source/SolidHole.cc;Source/SolidRidge.cc;Source/SolidSphere.cc;Source/SolidTube.cc;Source/SolidWire.cc;Source/TetrahedralTree.cc;Source/Track.cc;Source/TrackBichsel.cc;Source/TrackElectron.cc;Source/TrackHeed.cc;Source/TrackPAI.cc;Source/TrackSimple.cc;Source/TrackSrim.cc;Source/ViewBase.cc;Source/ViewCell.cc;Source/ViewDrift.cc;Source/ViewFEMesh.cc;Source/ViewField.cc;Source/ViewGeometry.cc;Source/ViewIsochrons.cc;Source/ViewMedium.cc;Source/ViewSignal.cc;GarfieldDict.cxx
-- -----------------------------------------------------------
-- Heed source files: Heed/HeedFieldMap.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/BGMesh.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/ElElasticScat.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/EnTransfCS.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/EnTransfCS_BGM.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/EnergyMesh.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/HeedCluster.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/HeedCondElectron.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/HeedDeltaElectron.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/HeedDeltaElectronCS.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/HeedMatterDef.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/HeedParticle.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/HeedParticle_BGM.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/HeedPhoton.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/PairProd.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/PhotoAbsCS.cpp;Heed/heed++/code/PhotoAbsCSLib.cpp;;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/box.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/circumf.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/gparticle.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/mparticle.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/plane.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/polyline.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/straight.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/surface.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/trajestep.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/vec.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/geometry/volume.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/ioniz/bethe_bloch.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/ioniz/e_cont_enloss.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/math/DoubleAc.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/math/PolLeg.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/math/cubic.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/math/kinem.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/math/linexi2.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/math/lorgamma.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/math/parabola.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/matrix/inverse.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/matrix/multiply.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/matter/AtomDef.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/matter/GasDef.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/matter/GasLib.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/matter/MatterDef.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/matter/MoleculeDef.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/particle/eparticle.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/particle/particle_def.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/random/PointsRan.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/random/chisran.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/random/pois.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/random/rnorm.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/safetl/AbsArr.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/safetl/AbsPtr.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/stream/definp.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/stream/findmark.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/stream/prstream.cpp;Heed/wcpplib/util/FunNameStack.cpp
-- -----------------------------------------------------------
-- Magboltz source files: Source/magboltz-11.9.f
-- -----------------------------------------------------------
-- neBEM source files: NeBem/ComputeProperties.c;NeBem/GarfieldppInterface.cpp;NeBem/Isles.c;NeBem/ReTriM.c;NeBem/Vector.c;NeBem/luc.c;NeBem/neBEM.c;NeBem/neBEMInterface.c;NeBem/nrutil.c;NeBem/svdcmp.c
-- -----------------------------------------------------------
-- Directory used to find ROOT dict files: 
-- -----------------------------------------------------------
-- Garfield++ examples will be built. In order disable this option use -DWITH_EXAMPLES=OFF
-- Install path: /usr/local
-- If you want to change this path call cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=my_install_path ...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/jason/GARFIELD/build
```

Notice the Root directory line is blank. How do I fix that?

Edit:2-

Measured success. Switched the location where ROOT is read from to where it was installed instead of where it was built and I got a new error message.

```
[  0%] Generating GarfieldDict.cxx, libGarfieldDict_rdict.pcm, libGarfieldDict.rootmap
No such file or directory
CMakeFiles/Garfield.dir/build.make:208: recipe for target 'GarfieldDict.cxx' failed
make[2]: *** [GarfieldDict.cxx] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Garfield.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Garfield.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Still emotionally processing the full implications.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps the problem is that you are trying to use `ROOT` from where `ROOT` is built and not from where it's installed? I started installing the `ROOT` packages (not building them manually) but they install so many dependencies that I won't be able to clean up afterwards :)

Comment: Seems to have helped actually, in the sense that I'm getting a new error message at least.